# How to avoid interceptions of the connection to the server in Android?

Tags: android, security, connection

In my Android app, I am getting the user information from server using a `HttpURLConnection`. Each user has a unique Id which may be accessed publicly.
Problem is if a third party, say, UserB has the Id of UserA, then they can abuse it by setting it inside my app (we know that how easy is to decompile Android APKs) then calling the server using my app and getting the output from server (including sensitive private information of UserA).

How can I prevent this from happening? What security tricks do you recommend?

Side note 1: I already have used encryption/decryption methods. But they are not going to stop UserB from abuse because when the UserB sets the Id of UserA, the app calls the server and then they have access to final decrypted output.

Side note 2: I have thought about Phone Number verification, but it is not operational for my app currently.

Side note 3: I cannot restrict the user to a specific device because they have to be able to use it on their different devices.

Side note 4: Libraries like Firebase, Gcm and the like are so secure. It would be a good idea to find out what ways they use to keep hackers from accessing another user's information!

Side note 5: Thanks to Gabor, I noticed that I had to mention that I cannot use a login interface unfortunately. If I could, that would be for sure a primary choice. It's the nature of my app and I can't change it!

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a very good question and a holy grail of all security officers :)

What's I learned is that whatever you do, as long as you cannot protect the physical device against unauthorized access, there's always a risk. The problem is:
* On the one hand, you wish that the app will keep and store an information which authorizes the owner of the device
* On the other hand, you have to protect this information on the device, but because your app needs to be able for accessing it, also the accessing algorithm must be available on the device.

So I would say, there's no "clear" way. What you can do, is to make the cost of obtaining information (in your case) unprofitable.

You said that the user ID is "publicly available". That's ok, but it means that the UserID is not "secure information". I would say, that your users need to be authorized first, and then the server should generate a UNIQUE token, that will be used in replacement of UserID when calling next requests.

You can implement it in many ways, but I will recommend one way, that should be not complex for your users:

1. Let's assume that all your users are registered. During the registration, each user needs to provide his email, UserID (could be generated) and password. Note that registration could be done in the mobile app or on the web portal.
2. When the app is going to start for the first time, a user should provide hist UserID (or simply email) and password.
3. With the first call to the server, the userID and password should be sent to the server, and server generated a Token (unique for every first login so even if the user will use two or more mobile devices each one will use the new token).
4. With every next call to the server, only the token needs to be provided to authenticate the user/device.

Where to store that token? No matter. I would say in any private storage of the app. You can and should, of course, encrypt it, obfuscate a so one, but whatever you do, if one has access to the device, he can always copy it.

You will say now, that it's not 100% secure. That's right. So I would say if it could not be secure, we should minimize the risk of abuse.

There are also some ways how one can do that.
First of all, in case of abuse, your users should be informed about it. Having a token algorithm, the user can take and action, and simply disable stolen tokens.
In case if the device has been for instance stolen, your users can/should be able to disable tokens (devices) on the web portal (or in another instance of the app) after signing in using email/password authentication.

The only one problem is how to detect that the mobile device has been "cloned". In that case, the user is physically not aware of the abuse.

My guess here is to implement the following algorithm (auth pooling):
1. Let the mobile app send the "keep alive" message with the Token to the server at the certain time when the app is inactive (let's say user xyz@gmail.com should send keepalive always at 10:00, 12:00 and so one).
2. Let the app send the keep alive, with some frequency when the user is logged in (app is active).
3. These frequencies/schedules must be know for the server and app (and could be even public).

In case if the server detects the same token in keep alive nearly the same time, the user should be informed (by the different channel, it could email) about possible abuse.
* NOTE: this is only an idea, I never did that, and I'm also wondering what other things about it, but in my opinion, this is quite simple to implement, and gives you a good change to minimize the risk.

Comment: Detailed answer! Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I cannot use any login procedure in my app :(

Comment: OK, so I need to ask you why? Your case is probably somehow specific and there's probably another way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

When a user starts using the app, they should log in using their credentials (eg. username and password). From the app's perspective, this is a roundtrip to the server to obtain a token. The token is then stored in the appropriate credential store for the platform you are using, and can be used to impersonate the user in further requests (the token can be sent with requests as for example an Authorize header, practically a bearer token). It also should have an expiry time, after which the user has to provide his credentials again.

Such a token can be a plain jwt you create, or it may come from something like a full oauth2 / openid connect implementation. If you decide to implement it yourself, be careful, it is not straightforward to get it right.

This way, you have proper authentication in place, you know who your users are in subsequent requests, and this way you can enforce access control rules on the server.

Comment: So sorry for not mentioning that I cannot use any login interface. I edited my question now thanks to your answer.

Comment: @SSP Then what you are after is impossible I'm afraid. You need to authenticate your user somehow, it's technically infeasible to securely authenticate the app itself.

Comment: Today developers widely use FCM, OneSignal and the like in their apps. How do they guarantee that their data is secure? I know there is no 100 percent guarantee, but I want to make it at least so hard for hackers to use just a packet sniff tool and call the server with it, maybe with minimal changes like setting a new Id! @Gabor

Comment: Actually, FMC uses a similar approach as described above. Basically, the user has to obtain a unique token and then you can manage this token, let the user create own account and so one. You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/